# How to format javascript array with lots of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, code-formatting

In javascript, I am creating an array with some values in it. The list of values is relatively long, and results in the single line of code appearing on two lines on most screens.  For example, the line of code is:

```
var fieldNames = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'emailAddress', 'hotelName', 'roundTrip', 'origin', 'departureDate', 'departureTime', 'returnDate', 'returnTime'];
```

Is there a preferred way to format this line so it's more readable? Should each value in the array be on its own line?

Comment: There are [many questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=code+formatting) on [code formatting](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-formatting) already, I am sure one of them covers this question.

Comment: Since my opinion is as good as anyones: If the array definition doesn't fit on one 80 character line, put every element on a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is more readable code, then putting each element separately on its own line works well.

For example, as is, if you make a change to an element in the array and commit to git, the whole line will show up as being changed in the diff. It is difficult for others to see exactly which element changed.

[image: change_element_on_one_line]

If each element is on its own line, and you make a change to an element then commit to git, then only the line with the changed element will show up in the diff. It is then obvious which element was changed.

[image: change_element_on_separate_lines]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do:

```js
var fieldNames = [
        'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'emailAddress', 'hotelName', 
        'roundTrip', 'origin', 'departureDate', 'departureTime', 'returnDate',
        'returnTime'
    ];
```

This is what I do. This may or may not be a good idea.

At least for me, it helps me to understand where the array starts and stops and what variable it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

We use require.js in our project and sometimes it happens that a module requires a lot of dependencies so our code looks like this:

```
require([
    module1,
    module2,
    module3,
    module4,
    module5,
    module6
], function(
    module1_obj,
    module2_obj,
    module3_obj,
    module4_obj,
    module5_obj,
    module6_obj
){
...
});
```

Because we have to define 2 lists that are really long we format it as a column, 1 item in one line, this way when we delete a dependency we can easily delete it in both columns and see that both have identical count of items.

**Clarification:** first array in require.js defines dependencies and the second gives an object to use of that dependency that is the reason why there are two.

Benefits of not placing any item in first line

```
var foo = [ // <-- Not having an element on this line.
    1,
    2,
    3
];
```

Is that then the array is defined in the same fashion as object is usually:

```
var bar = {
    iAmAProperty: "YAY"
};
```

And in version control you can clearly see if the content of object/array is edited or the name of the object/array

Answer (score -1):

```
var fieldNames = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'emailAddress', 
'hotelName', 'roundTrip', 'origin', 'departureDate', 'departureTime',
'returnDate', 'returnTime'];
```